# flexslider plugin and knockout issue

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, flexslider

I have a terrible problem using konckout and flexslider plugin on my application. The flexlider plugin loads the images on the li elements but the li elements have an inline stile with an alpha:0, so the plugin loads correctly but i can't see the images that it have. 
I try to use the

```
$('.flexslider').removeData("flexslider");
```

but didn't work.  I try to make a special binding handler but did'nt work:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.flexslideUI = {
        init: function (element) {
            $(element).flexslider();
        },
        update: function (element) {
            $(element).flexslider('refresh');
        }
    };
```

Here I left some explaining code hoping someone can help me with this trouble:

// binding handlers and

```
    //update widgets function
    ko.bindingHandlers.udpateWidgets = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {

            $('.flexslider').flexslider();

        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {

              $('.flexslider').flexslider();
                $("a[data-rel^='tooltip']").tooltip();
                $("a[data-rel^='tooltip']").attr("onclick", "javascript:return false;");
            }
        };

    function myViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.myArray = ko.observableArray();

        self.showRecommended = ko.observable(false);
        self.showSpecial = ko.observable(false);


        self.sortDirections = ko.observableArray([
        {
            name: "Sort By",
            price: null,
            rate: null
        },
         {
            name: "Price Asc",
            price: false,
            rate: null
        },
        {
            name: "Price Desc",
            price: true,
            rate: null
        },
        {
            name: "Rate Asc",
            price: null,
            rate: false
        },
        {
            name: "Rate Desc",
            price: null,
            rate: true
        }]);

        //sorting filtering function
        self.currentSortDirection = ko.observable(self.sortDirections()[0]);

        self.elementsToShow = ko.pureComputed(function () {

            var recomend = self.showRecommended();
            var special = self.showSpecial();
            var sorting = self.currentSortDirection();

            if (!recomend && !special) return self.myArray().sort(function (a, b) {

                if (sorting.price != null) {
                    var fp = sorting.price ? -1 : 1;
                    ap = parseInt(a.price);
                    bp = parseInt(b.price);
                    return ap == bp ? 0 : (fp * (ap < bp ? -1 : 1));
                }
                else if (sorting.rate != null) {
                    var f = sorting.rate ? -1 : 1;
                    ar = parseFloat(a.rating);
                    br = parseFloat(b.rating);
                    return ar == br ? 0 : (f * (ar < br ? -1 : 1));
                }
            });

            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.myArray(), function (element) {
                return (element.recommended != "0" && recomend) || (element.offer != "" && special);
            }).sort(function (a, b) {
                debugger;
                if (sorting.price != null) {
                    var fs = sorting.price ? -1 : 1;
                    ap = a.price;
                    bp = b.price;
                    return ap == bp ? 0 : (fs * (ap < bp ? -1 : 1));
                }
                if (sorting.rating != null) {
                    var fu = sorting.rate ? -1 : 1;
                    ar = a.rating;
                    br = b.rating;
                    return ar == br ? 0 : (fu * (ar < br ? -1 : 1));
                }
            });
        }, self);


         self.loadUI = function(){
            $('.flexslider').flexslider();

           //reload tooltip and disable onclic event
        $("a[data-rel^='tooltip']").tooltip();
        $("a[data-rel^='tooltip']").attr("onclick", "javascript:return false;")
        }

self.Search = function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "mydomain/Find",
                data: "searchExpressionString:exp",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                cache: false,

                success: function (result) {
                    var response = $.parseJSON(result);
                        self.myArray(response.array);
                        // window.location.search +='&'+searchExp;

                    self.loadUI();
                },
                error: function(a, desc, error) {

                        // window.location.search +='&'+searchExp;
                    }
                   // self.loadUI();
                },
            });

    }
    //end viewModel
    $(function(){

        var model = new myViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(model);

    });
</script>

<!--  search button, loads content -->
<button data-bind='click:Search' id="searchbutton">search</button>
<!--sorting elements -->
<div class="sortbuttons" style="text-align: left;">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <strong>SHOW ONLY: </strong>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <label><input type='checkbox' name="rock" data-bind='checked: showRecommended' />Recommended</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <label><input type='checkbox' name="gas" data-bind='checked: showSpecial' />Special Offer</label>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
<select data-bind="options: sortDirections, optionsText: 'name', value: currentSortDirection"></select>

<!-- part of the page that I bind the slider -->
 <div data-bind='foreach: elementsToShow'>
                <div class="post-thumb-wrap span5" data-bind="udpateWidgets:true">
                          <div class="flexslider" id="slider">
                        <a data-bind="attr: { 'href': $data.pageUrl }" target="_blank">
                            <ul class="slides" data-bind='foreach: imagePaths'>
                                <li>
                                    <img data-bind="attr: { 'src': $data.srcImg, 'alt': $data.keywords }" itemprop="image" />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="shortl-btn">
                        <a class="button button-darkgray" data-bind="attr : {'href': $data.pageUrl}">
                            <i class="icon-signin"></i>More Details
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>

//my array data have this structure, I put it in myArray using $.parseJSON of a response using ajax
{
            'array': [
            {
            'rating': '5',

            'imagePaths':[
            {
            'srcImg': 'fun.jpg',
            'keywords': '1234'
            },
            {
            'srcImg': 'sun.jpg',
            'keywords': '1234'
            },
            {
            'srcImg': 'pape.jpg',
            'keywords': '212'
            }
            ],
            'price': '43',
            'offer': '',
            'recommended': '0',

            },
            {
            'rating': '3',

            'imagePaths':[
            {
            'srcImg': 'fun.jpg',
            'keywords': '1234'
            },
            {
            'srcImg': 'sun.jpg',
            'keywords': '1234'
            },
            {
            'srcImg': 'pape.jpg',
            'keywords': '212'
            }
            ],
            'price': '143',
            'offer': '12',
            'recommended': '1',

            },
            {
            'rating': '2',

            'imagePaths':[
            {
            'srcImg': 'fun.jpg',
            'keywords': '1234'
            },
            {
            'srcImg': 'sun.jpg',
            'keywords': '1234'
            },
            {
            'srcImg': 'pape.jpg',
            'keywords': '212'
            }
            ],
            'price': '443',
            'offer': '34',
            'recommended': '0',

            },
            {
            'rating': '3.8',

            'imagePaths':[
            {
            'srcImg': 'fun.jpg',
            'keywords': '1234'
            },
            {
            'srcImg': 'sun.jpg',
            'keywords': '1234'
            },
            {
            'srcImg': 'pape.jpg',
            'keywords': '212'
            }
            ],
            'price': '843',
            'offer': '23',
            'recommended': '1',

            },
            {
            'rating': '4',

            'imagePaths':[
            {
            'srcImg': 'fun.jpg',
            'keywords': '1234'
            },
            {
            'srcImg': 'sun.jpg',
            'keywords': '1234'
            },
            {
            'srcImg': 'pape.jpg',
            'keywords': '212'
            }
            ],
            'price': '233',
            'offer': '',
            'recommended': '0',

            }
            ]
            }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use finally a template binding that re-render the elements on each population of the template, avoiding the use of the foreach and the re-render of complements plugins inside it.

from [knockout website](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html)

> The template binding populates the associated DOM element with the results of rendering a template. Templates are a simple and convenient way to build sophisticated UI structures - possibly with repeating or nested blocks - as a function of your view model data.
>
> There are two main ways of using templates:
>
> Native templating is the mechanism that underpins foreach, if, with, and other control flow bindings. Internally, those control flow bindings capture the HTML markup contained in your element, and use it as a template to render against an arbitrary data item. This feature is built into Knockout and doesn’t require any external library.
>
> String-based templating is a way to connect Knockout to a third-party template engine. Knockout will pass your model values to the external template engine and inject the resulting markup string into your document. See below for examples that use the jquery.tmpl and Underscore template engines.

So, I use

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'my-template', foreach: myArray(), afterRender: resetrUI }">
```

And I use this function on myViewModel

```
resetrUI = function (elements) {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
}
```

[Another biblio here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/06/10-things-to-know-about-knockoutjs-on.html)

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Artjon B. Answer added correctly.